# Convert a Column of Character Vectors into Single Row

Tags: r

Need help in converting a dataset akin to the one below:

```
unique_column   final_string
13_AR4X5JP5LR64V    c("bollywood Bollywood_Movies", "comedy Bollywood_Movies", "romance Bollywood_Movies", "world_cinema Bollywood_Movies")
13_AR4X5JP5LR64V    c("comedy US_TV", "drama US_TV")
17_AR5JKJP5LR96V    c("comedy IN_TV", "romance IN_TV", "world_cinema IN_TV")
17_AR5JKJP5LR96V    c("comedy IN_TV", "drama US_TV")
17_AR5JKJP5LR96V    c("drama US_TV", "thriller US_TV")
```

I want to convert this into one row for each value in the unique column. With each character vector concatenated. Into a dataframe similar to this:

```
unique_column   final_string
13_AR4X5JP5LR64V    bollywood Bollywood_Movies,comedy Bollywood_Movies,romance Bollywood_Movies,world_cinema Bollywood_Movies,comedy US_TV,drama US_TV
17_AR5JKJP5LR96V    comedy IN_TV,romance IN_TV,world_cinema IN_TV,comedy IN_TV,drama US_TV,drama US_TV,thriller US_TV
```

I am using loops at the moment to process this, but that is quite slow. let me know if there is another faster way of doing this processing.

In for loops, i am using the following code:

```
genres <- paste(unlist(data$final_string), collapse=',')
```

let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Could you please provide a `dput()` of your example data. For instance if the example data set is called `mylist` please type `dput(mylist)` then copy the output and paste it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this working?

```
library(dplyr)
df_new <- df %>% group_by(unique_column) %>% summarise(final_string= unlist(paste(unlist(final_string),collapse=",")))
df_new <- as.data.frame(df_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ?

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%rowwise()%>%mutate(final_string=toString(unlist(final_string)))
```